# Blank responsive banner on cellphone and tablet (sizeMapping)

Tags: adsense, google-dfp, ads

I have a custom 1600x433 banner, I've created it as responsive and I'm trying to use sizeMapping, on the desktop the banner works, however, on the tablet and mobile the banner area just goes blank.

Set custom sizes in settings> sizes. The original image has exactly. 1600x433 What am I doing wrong that the banner is not responsive as I customize it?

googletag.cmd.push(function() {

```
        var mapping = googletag.sizeMapping().


             // Accepts both common mobile banner formats
             addSize([320, 400], [320, 50]). 

             // Same width as mapping above, more available height
             addSize([320, 700], [360, 100]).

             // Desktop
             addSize([1050, 200], [1600, 433]).build();


      googletag.defineSlot('/id/sitenovo',[320, 50], 'div-gpt-ad-0').defineSizeMapping(mapping).addService(googletag.pubads());
          googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
          googletag.enableServices();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Size [320, 400] matches a viewport greater than or equal to 320, 400 pixels. Use a size [0,0